# Local Function access parent variables with same name

Tags: android, kotlin

this is more of a curiosity question that came up during my presentation on kotlin

I am using a local function, and it has same parameter name as its parent.

Look at this example:

```
fun outerFunction(a: Int, b:Int) {

    fun localFunction(a: Int) {
        print(a) //local a
        print(b) //parent b
        print(???) //parent a?
    }

}
```

inside the local Function, I'm printing the local a, the parent b, and is there any way to print the parent a?

Comment: Thankfully, there isn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From a `bytecode`'s point of view, this would be possible, because the variables of `outerFunction` are just fields in the `localFunction`'s inner class (in the bytecode), to they would be accessible.

```
// decompiled localFunction
implements Function1<Integer, Unit> {
    final /* synthetic */ int $b;

    public final void invoke(int a) {
        System.out.print(a);
        int n = this.$b;
        System.out.print(n);
    }
    ...
}
```

Luckily, kotlin doesn't support's this, because that just will generate ambiguity for the programmer and is error prone.

So avoid using the same name for variables which are already used somewhere in an outer-scope